# Сложный запрос SQL

Tags: mysql

Имеется таблица:

```
article
___________
id|IdCategory
```

И таблица категорий:

```
article_category
___________
idCategory|Name
```

И третья таблица, содержит Id пользователей, кто поставил LIKE к категориям статей

```
article_likes
___________
id|idCategory|idUser
```

Нужно выбрать все записи из таблицы **article**, отсортированные по наибольшим лайкам, к которым каждая из статей относится.

Comment: Если каждая статья относится к одной категории, то вроде так:

    select a.id 
      from article a join 
        (select a1.id, count(*) cnt from article_likes a1 group by a1.id) c
           on a.id = c.id 
    order by a.idCategory, c.cnt desc

Упорядочено по категориям, а внутри по количеству лайков (по убыванию)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал так, один лишь вопрос, в чем различие между `JOIN ... ON (tb.поле1=tb.поле2 AND tb.поле3 = 7)` и вот этим, но уже вне **ON**: `WHERE tb.поле3 = 7`?

```
    SELECT a . * , COUNT( su.idSubscrubeToUsers ) AS SBS
FROM  `article` a

LEFT JOIN article_category ac ON ac.article_categoryIdArticle = a.idArticle

LEFT JOIN subscrubetousers su ON ( su.SubscrubeToUsersIdNote = ac.article_categoryIdCatgory
AND SubscrubeToUsersType =1 ) 
GROUP BY a.idArticle
ORDER BY SBS DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```